# Prove Perfect square of the form 4k or 4k+1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So i want to prove that every perfect square is of the form 4k or 4k+1, can someone tell me how to do this. Really need help with this

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What do you know about perfect squares that you think might be useful?

Comment: so I know that this statement is true and that perfect squares are product of rational number multiplied by iteself

Comment: We look at the perfect square $x^2$. There are two possibilities, (i) $x$ is even and (ii) $x$ is odd.

Comment: so how can that help us

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that a perfect square is either a multiple of $4$ or of the form $4q+1$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518879/prove-that-a-perfect-square-is-either-a-multiple-of-4-or-of-the-form-4q1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any natural number is either even or odd. 
So any natural number can be represented as $2n$ or $2n+1$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, $(2n)^2=4n^2$ which is of the form $4k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ 
AND 
$(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1=4n(n+1)+1$ which is of the form $4k+1$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that quick response guys really helpful and Thankyou

Comment: @SyedNaqi You're welcome. You can accept my answer by clicking the "tick" mark beside my answer.

Comment: it won't let me after 7 min i can accept an answer. also btw how did you do this because I don't know how to do these discrete math problem every time I try to I always get stuck with these logical question

Comment: Actually, for any such discrete math problem, you need to start your problem from the basics. Consider what kind of numbers are suitable for your problem,  the representation I used here is useful in many problems. And the more you practise such problems, the more you will learn.

Answer (score 4):

For every square $a^2$ there are two possible cases:

- Case 1: $a^2$ is even. Then, it is the square of an even number $a = 2n \Rightarrow a^2 = 4n^2 = 4k$
- Case 2: $a^2$ is odd. Then, it is the square of an odd number $a = 2n + 1 \Rightarrow a^2 = 4n^2 +4n + 1= 4(n^2 + n) + 1 = 4k + 1$